# smtplib subject field TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtplib

I am trying to add string value to subject field while sending email using smtplib, but unfortunately, msg['Subject'] always throws the error:

TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Below is my code:

```
    for host in self.hostnames:
        for h in host:
            start = 'Create'
            s = str(h)
            l = str(self.lease)
            u = str(self.username)
            f = str(listFlavor)
            subject = start + ' ' + s + ' ' + l + ' ' + u + ' ' + f

            msg            = 'Add Lease days of %s' % str(self.lease)
            msg['Subject'] = subject
            msg['From']    = self.username
            msg['To']      = 'test@test.com'

            s = smtplib.SMTP('test.test.com')
            s.sendmail('test@test.com', self.username, msg.as_string())
            s.quit()
```

Comment: `msg` is a string. What do you expect `msg['Subject'] = subject` to do?

Answer (score 2):

yes that's true.

I have added this line to initially declare msg.

`msg = MIMEMultipart('related')`

which is a dict and holds the values added to msg.